# Python: Combining images using paste with overlapping pixels and areas with alpha channel=0

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, paste

I am trying to combine three images together.  The image I want on the bottom is a 700x900 image with all black pixels.  On top of that I want to paste an image that is 400x400 with an offset of 100,200.  On top of that I want to paste an image border that is 700x900.  The image border has alpha=0 in the inside of it and alpha=0 around it because it doesn't have straight edges.  When I run the code I have pasted below I encounter 2 problems:

1) Everywhere on the border image where the alpha channel = 0, the alpha channel has been set to 255 and the color white shows instead of the black background and the image I am putting the border around.

2) The border image's quality has been significantly reduced and looks a lot different than it should.

Also: part of the border image will cover part of the Image I am putting the border around.  So I can't just switch the order that I am pasting.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

from PIL import ImageTk, Image

old_im2 = Image.open('backgroundImage1.jpg') # size = 400x400
old_im = Image.open('topImage.png') # size = 700x900
new_size = (700,900)
new_im = Image.new("RGBA", new_size) # makes the black image
new_im.paste(old_im2, (100, 200))
new_im.paste(old_im,(0,0))

new_im.show()
new_im.save('final.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about images - the border image **does have pixels everywhere**.  It's not possible for it to be "missing" pixels.  It is possible to have an image with an alpha channel, which is a channel like the `R`, `G`, and `B` channels, but indicates transparency.

Try this:

1. Make sure that `topImage.png` has a transparency channel, and that the pixels that you want to be "missing" are transparent (i.e. have a maximum alpha value).  You can double check this way:

```
print old_im.mode  # This should print "RGBA" if it has an alpha channel.
```

2. Create `new_im` in "RGBA" mode:

```
new_im = Image.new("RGBA", new_size) # makes the black image
# Note the "A" --------^
```

3. Try this paste statement instead:

```
new_im.paste(old_im,(0,0), mask=old_im)  # Using old_im as the mask argument should tell the paste function to use old_im's alpha channel to combine the two images.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I believe I have a transparency channel on the topimage.png (when I look at it in gimp it is there) but when I paste it with python it disappears.  Is there a flag or something that I can set so that it keeps my alpha channel in mind when pasting.

Comment: Thanks so much this fixed all of the issues!